# probability with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

according to the experience of a bank staff,there are 2 old paper money IN EACH MONEY PACKET.if the number of old papers money,in each money packet,follow poisson distribution,

- a)what is the probability of that ,there is'nt any old paper money in
  two money packets?
- b)what is the probability of that ,there are more than 5 old papers
  money in two money packets?

i'll tried for a:

```
for (a),i think : 1-((e^-2)(2^x))/x!
```

Comment: $1 - e^2 \approx -6.4 $ so that is not a probability

Comment: @SteveODonnell you right, i'v edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

a) Obviously the probability there's no old money in 1 money packet is $p_s=e^{-2}$. Since you have two and these events are independent, the probability there's none in 2 is [can you handle from here?]

b) The probability that there are moer than 5 old money banknotes is $1$-probability there are 4 or less. Can you handle from here?

Comment: i agree with your solution for b,but i'm searching for a formula for that.

Comment: Are you familiar with cumulative distribution function?